# Запятая при однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом и

Tags: пунктуация

Образуется ли здесь тесное смысловое единство или разработчик и производитель - это все же разные понятия?

И наш институт, являющийся и разработчиком и производителем ТПА, также можно отнести к представителям малого бизнеса.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, вопрос снялся сам собой... Очевидно, что здесь обычные однородные члены и ни о каком смысловом единстве речь не идет.

Answer (score 1):

В правилах говорится: При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом и, запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (***обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов***): Кругом было и светло и зелено (Т.);

При ***наличии пояснительных слов при одном из двух однородных членов*** предложения между ними ***ставится запятая:*** Срубленные осины придавили собой и траву, и ***мелкий кустарник***.

В вашем примере нет  зависимого слова при однородном члене, а отсутствие запятой указывает на тесную смысловую (в данном случае умственно-физическую) связь.

Comment: Серж!.. Все-таки разрабатывать и производить - это разные вещи, хотя в данном случае институт объединяет в себе эти два процесса... Но в интернете нашла подобный пример через запятую: "Компания Modellini является и разработчиком, и производителем всех своих коллекций женского трикотажа". Конечно, не все то, что можно найти в интернете, является правильным... в 50 % случаев - наоборот... но все же...

Comment: Аленка, мой знакомый показал мне впрос, который он задал Грамме.ру. Вот что они ответили.

Comment: Надежных показателей, однозначно указывающих на смысловое единство слов, соединенных повторяющимся союзом "и", нет. Более того, в некоторых случаях возможно двоякое прочтение примеров, что приводит к варьированию их пунктуационного оформления.

Comment: Среди критериев, указывающих на смысловое единство однородных членов, можно отметить семантический критерий (объединяемые члены часто (хотя и не всегда) возводимы к более общему понятию, ср.: и день и ночь = "сутки", и мать и отец = "родители"), который, собственно говоря, и обусловливает требование об отсутствии у однородных членов зависимых слов, а также связанный с семантическим критерием интонационный критерий (соединяемые слова произносятся не раздельно, а слитно; невозможно ударение на повторяющемся союзе "и").

Comment: Некоторые примеры, как уже отмечено, допускают двоякую трактовку, причем если преобладает раздельность, то "и... и" можно заменить на союз "как... так и".

Comment: Так что можно сделать вывод, ваш пример допускает обе трактовки.